Tiny red parasites
I have been finding super tiny red parasites all over the garden and some of them even found their way to my indoors plants. After a quick research I believe they are Spider Mites but I am not too sure if that is indeed what they are.
My question is, how do I get rid of them? Both inside the house and on the garden.
Also, how harmful are they?

Pictures please, I note that most spider mites look like grains of salt so it could just be red insects

@kevinskio Yes they are about that size...

While spider mites spin tiny webs, they do smear red in your hands. Did you try neem oil or soapy water?

@YosefBaskin I haven't yet! What soap can I use? Normal dish soap? Hand soup? (They are on top of some plants and I don't want to damage them)

I use dish soap, anything sorta edible/natural/castile.

@YosefBaskin Thank you! Will try that!
